# Проблема отображения таблиц Dash Plotly

Tags: python, css, plotly, dash

Столкнулся с проблемой отображения таблиц в дашбордах через Dash Plotly.
Изначально таблицы выглядели как на скриншоте 1, затем в какой-то момент стали как на скриншоте 2. При этом никакие параметры не менялись.
Изменение параметра height в style_cells теперь никак не влияет на визуальный вид таблицы, ничего не меняется.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема и как ее решить.
Код таблицы:

```
dash_table.DataTable(
                id='my-datatable-1',
                page_size=40,
                style_table={'overflowX': 'auto'},
                style_cell={'fontSize':9, 'font-family':'sans-serif','whiteSpace': 'normal','padding': '0px','height': '10%'},
                style_data_conditional=[
                {
                    'if': {
                        'filter_query': '{2-х недельная динамика} contains "#"'
                    },
                    'backgroundColor': '#c8d4e4',
                    'color': 'black'
                }],
                style_as_list_view=False,
                style_header={'fontWeight': 'bold'}
                )
```

[image: Было]

[image: Стало]